# ruby on rails benchmark vs sql benchmark. Which should you use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have 2 pairs of sql query. 1 from postgresql for testing, and 1 from ruby on rails

Here is with Left join with inner left join to get the sap_temporary.name and sap_default.name

```
select 
su.id AS user_id, 
su.email,
su.doctor,
sca.id AS copr_accnt_id,
sca.company_id,
sca.company_name,
sap_default.variant_price_set_id AS sap_default_id,
sap_default.name AS sap_default_name,
sap_temporary.variant_price_set_id AS sap_temporary_id,
sap_temporary.name AS sap_temporary_name
from spree_corporate_accounts sca
INNER JOIN "spree_memberships" sm
  ON "sm"."corporate_account_id" = "sca"."id"
  AND "sm"."deleted_at" IS NULL
INNER JOIN "spree_users" su
  ON "su"."id" = "sm"."user_id"
  AND "su"."deleted_at" IS NULL
LEFT JOIN (
    select
    sap.id,
    sap.accountable_id, 
    sap.accountable_type,
    sap.variant_price_set_id,
    svps.name
    from spree_account_prices sap
    left join spree_variant_price_sets svps on sap.variant_price_set_id = svps.id
    where status = 'default'
) sap_default on sap_default.accountable_id = sca.id and sap_default.accountable_type = 'Spree::CorporateAccount'
LEFT JOIN (
    select
    sap.id,
    sap.accountable_id, 
    sap.accountable_type,
    sap.variant_price_set_id,
    svps.name
    from spree_account_prices sap
    left join spree_variant_price_sets svps on sap.variant_price_set_id = svps.id
    where status = 'temporary'
) sap_temporary on sap_temporary.accountable_id = sca.id and sap_temporary.accountable_type = 'Spree::CorporateAccount';
```

Result from postgres USING EXPLAIN YAML FORMAT

```
- Plan: 
    Node Type: "Nested Loop"
    Parallel Aware: false
    Join Type: "Left"
    Startup Cost: 1.32
    Total Cost: 12.12
    Plan Rows: 1
    Plan Width: 187
    Join Filter: "(sap_1.variant_price_set_id = svps_1.id)"
    Plans: 
      - Node Type: "Nested Loop"
        Parent Relationship: "Outer"
        Parallel Aware: false
        Join Type: "Left"
        Startup Cost: 1.32
        Total Cost: 11.05
        Plan Rows: 1
        Plan Width: 155
        Join Filter: "(sap_1.accountable_id = sca.id)"
        Plans: 
          - Node Type: "Nested Loop"
            Parent Relationship: "Outer"
            Parallel Aware: false
            Join Type: "Left"
            Startup Cost: 1.32
            Total Cost: 9.10
            Plan Rows: 1
            Plan Width: 151
            Join Filter: "(sap.variant_price_set_id = svps.id)"
            Plans: 
              - Node Type: "Nested Loop"
                Parent Relationship: "Outer"
                Parallel Aware: false
                Join Type: "Left"
                Startup Cost: 1.32
                Total Cost: 8.03
                Plan Rows: 1
                Plan Width: 119
                Join Filter: "(sap.accountable_id = sca.id)"
                Plans: 
                  - Node Type: "Nested Loop"
                    Parent Relationship: "Outer"
                    Parallel Aware: false
                    Join Type: "Inner"
                    Startup Cost: 1.32
                    Total Cost: 6.08
                    Plan Rows: 1
                    Plan Width: 115
                    Join Filter: "(sm.corporate_account_id = sca.id)"
                    Plans: 
                      - Node Type: "Hash Join"
                        Parent Relationship: "Outer"
                        Parallel Aware: false
                        Join Type: "Inner"
                        Startup Cost: 1.32
                        Total Cost: 4.99
                        Plan Rows: 1
                        Plan Width: 51
                        Hash Cond: "(su.id = sm.user_id)"
                        Plans: 
                          - Node Type: "Seq Scan"
                            Parent Relationship: "Outer"
                            Parallel Aware: false
                            Relation Name: "spree_users"
                            Alias: "su"
                            Startup Cost: 0.00
                            Total Cost: 3.56
                            Plan Rows: 27
                            Plan Width: 47
                            Filter: "(deleted_at IS NULL)"
                          - Node Type: "Hash"
                            Parent Relationship: "Inner"
                            Parallel Aware: false
                            Startup Cost: 1.31
                            Total Cost: 1.31
                            Plan Rows: 1
                            Plan Width: 8
                            Plans: 
                              - Node Type: "Seq Scan"
                                Parent Relationship: "Outer"
                                Parallel Aware: false
                                Relation Name: "spree_memberships"
                                Alias: "sm"
                                Startup Cost: 0.00
                                Total Cost: 1.31
                                Plan Rows: 1
                                Plan Width: 8
                                Filter: "(deleted_at IS NULL)"
                      - Node Type: "Seq Scan"
                        Parent Relationship: "Inner"
                        Parallel Aware: false
                        Relation Name: "spree_corporate_accounts"
                        Alias: "sca"
                        Startup Cost: 0.00
                        Total Cost: 1.04
                        Plan Rows: 4
                        Plan Width: 68
                  - Node Type: "Seq Scan"
                    Parent Relationship: "Inner"
                    Parallel Aware: false
                    Relation Name: "spree_account_prices"
                    Alias: "sap"
                    Startup Cost: 0.00
                    Total Cost: 1.90
                    Plan Rows: 4
                    Plan Width: 8
                    Filter: "(((status)::text = 'default'::text) AND ((accountable_type)::text = 'Spree::CorporateAccount'::text))"
              - Node Type: "Seq Scan"
                Parent Relationship: "Inner"
                Parallel Aware: false
                Relation Name: "spree_variant_price_sets"
                Alias: "svps"
                Startup Cost: 0.00
                Total Cost: 1.03
                Plan Rows: 3
                Plan Width: 36
          - Node Type: "Seq Scan"
            Parent Relationship: "Inner"
            Parallel Aware: false
            Relation Name: "spree_account_prices"
            Alias: "sap_1"
            Startup Cost: 0.00
            Total Cost: 1.90
            Plan Rows: 4
            Plan Width: 8
            Filter: "(((status)::text = 'temporary'::text) AND ((accountable_type)::text = 'Spree::CorporateAccount'::text))"
      - Node Type: "Seq Scan"
        Parent Relationship: "Inner"
        Parallel Aware: false
        Relation Name: "spree_variant_price_sets"
        Alias: "svps_1"
        Startup Cost: 0.00
        Total Cost: 1.03
        Plan Rows: 3
        Plan Width: 36
```

Here is the Ruby on Rails query

```
@search = Spree::CorporateAccount.joins(memberships: [:user])
                                         .joins("LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                                                              sap.accountable_id, 
                                                              sap.accountable_type, 
                                                              sap.variant_price_set_id,
                                                              svps.name
                                                            FROM 
                                                              spree_account_prices sap
                                                              LEFT JOIN spree_variant_price_sets svps on sap.variant_price_set_id = svps.id
                                                              where status = 'default' 
                                                            ) sap_default on sap_default.accountable_id = spree_corporate_accounts.id and sap_default.accountable_type = 'Spree::CorporateAccount' ")
                                         .joins("LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                                                              sap.accountable_id,
                                                              sap.accountable_type,
                                                              sap.variant_price_set_id,
                                                              svps.name
                                                            FROM 
                                                              spree_account_prices sap
                                                              LEFT JOIN spree_variant_price_sets svps on sap.variant_price_set_id = svps.id
                                                              where status = 'temporary' 
                                                            ) sap_temporary on sap_temporary.accountable_id = spree_corporate_accounts.id and sap_temporary.accountable_type = 'Spree::CorporateAccount' ")
                                         .joins('LEFT JOIN spree_addresses ON spree_addresses.id = spree_corporate_accounts.bill_address_id')
                                         .joins('LEFT JOIN spree_states ON spree_states.id = spree_addresses.state_id')
                                         .joins('LEFT JOIN spree_countries ON spree_countries.id = spree_addresses.country_id')
                                         .where('spree_memberships.deleted_at IS NULL')
                                         .order('spree_corporate_accounts.company_name')
                                         .order('spree_memberships.admin DESC')
                                         .ransack(params[:q])
```

here is the benchmark/result for joins

```
0.010000    0.000000    0.010000    (  0.011334)
0.030000    0.000000    0.030000    (  0.030845)
0.010000    0.000000    0.010000    (  0.013424)
0.010000    0.000000    0.010000    (  0.012594)
0.010000    0.000000    0.010000    (  0.012120)
```

the pluck for getting the data

```
        @corporate_user_list = @search.result.pluck('spree_corporate_accounts.id',
                                                    'spree_corporate_accounts.company_name',
                                                    'spree_memberships.admin',
                                                    'spree_users.email',
                                                    'spree_users.doctor AS NAME',
                                                    'coalesce(spree_corporate_accounts.account_key, spree_users.account_key) as effective_account_key',
                                                    "CASE spree_corporate_accounts.billing_type when 1 THEN 'Postbill' WHEN 2 THEN 'Creditcard' ELSE 'Individual'END",
                                                    "sap_default.name",
                                                    "sap_temporary.name",
                                                    'spree_addresses.address1',
                                                    'spree_addresses.address2',
                                                    'spree_addresses.city',
                                                    'spree_addresses.zipcode',
                                                    'spree_states.name AS state',
                                                    'spree_countries.name AS country',
                                                    'spree_addresses.phone',
                                                    "spree_users.created_at")
```

benchmark result from pluck

```
0.010000    0.000000    0.010000    (  0.020869)
0.020000    0.000000    0.020000    (  0.022321)
0.020000    0.000000    0.020000    (  0.021910)
0.010000    0.000000    0.010000    (  0.019196)
0.010000    0.000000    0.010000    (  0.014794)
```

-------------------++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++----------------------

Here is the second query Postgres and ruby on rails with result

postgres query with inner select

```
SELECT 
su.id AS user_id, 
su.email,
su.doctor,
sca.id AS copr_accnt_id,
sca.company_id,
sca.company_name,
sap_default.variant_price_set_id AS sap_default_id,
sap_temporary.variant_price_set_id AS sap_temporary_id,
(SELECT name FROM spree_variant_price_sets where id = sap_default.variant_price_set_id ) AS default, 
(SELECT name FROM spree_variant_price_sets where id = sap_temporary.variant_price_set_id) As temporary
from spree_corporate_accounts sca
INNER JOIN "spree_memberships" sm
  ON "sm"."corporate_account_id" = "sca"."id"
  AND "sm"."deleted_at" IS NULL
INNER JOIN "spree_users" su
  ON "su"."id" = "sm"."user_id"
  AND "su"."deleted_at" IS NULL
-- where sca.id in (5)
LEFT JOIN (
    select
    sap.id,
    sap.accountable_id, 
    sap.accountable_type,
    sap.variant_price_set_id
    from spree_account_prices sap
    where status = 'default'
) sap_default on sap_default.accountable_id = sca.id and sap_default.accountable_type = 'Spree::CorporateAccount'
LEFT JOIN (
    select
    sap.id,
    sap.accountable_id, 
    sap.accountable_type,
    sap.variant_price_set_id
    from spree_account_prices sap
    where status = 'temporary'
) sap_temporary on sap_temporary.accountable_id = sca.id and sap_temporary.accountable_type = 'Spree::CorporateAccount';
```

result benchmark postgresql format YAML

```
- Plan: 
    Node Type: "Nested Loop"
    Parallel Aware: false
    Join Type: "Left"
    Startup Cost: 1.32
    Total Cost: 12.06
    Plan Rows: 1
    Plan Width: 187
    Join Filter: "(sap_1.accountable_id = sca.id)"
    Plans: 
      - Node Type: "Nested Loop"
        Parent Relationship: "Outer"
        Parallel Aware: false
        Join Type: "Left"
        Startup Cost: 1.32
        Total Cost: 8.03
        Plan Rows: 1
        Plan Width: 119
        Join Filter: "(sap.accountable_id = sca.id)"
        Plans: 
          - Node Type: "Nested Loop"
            Parent Relationship: "Outer"
            Parallel Aware: false
            Join Type: "Inner"
            Startup Cost: 1.32
            Total Cost: 6.08
            Plan Rows: 1
            Plan Width: 115
            Join Filter: "(sm.corporate_account_id = sca.id)"
            Plans: 
              - Node Type: "Hash Join"
                Parent Relationship: "Outer"
                Parallel Aware: false
                Join Type: "Inner"
                Startup Cost: 1.32
                Total Cost: 4.99
                Plan Rows: 1
                Plan Width: 51
                Hash Cond: "(su.id = sm.user_id)"
                Plans: 
                  - Node Type: "Seq Scan"
                    Parent Relationship: "Outer"
                    Parallel Aware: false
                    Relation Name: "spree_users"
                    Alias: "su"
                    Startup Cost: 0.00
                    Total Cost: 3.56
                    Plan Rows: 27
                    Plan Width: 47
                    Filter: "(deleted_at IS NULL)"
                  - Node Type: "Hash"
                    Parent Relationship: "Inner"
                    Parallel Aware: false
                    Startup Cost: 1.31
                    Total Cost: 1.31
                    Plan Rows: 1
                    Plan Width: 8
                    Plans: 
                      - Node Type: "Seq Scan"
                        Parent Relationship: "Outer"
                        Parallel Aware: false
                        Relation Name: "spree_memberships"
                        Alias: "sm"
                        Startup Cost: 0.00
                        Total Cost: 1.31
                        Plan Rows: 1
                        Plan Width: 8
                        Filter: "(deleted_at IS NULL)"
              - Node Type: "Seq Scan"
                Parent Relationship: "Inner"
                Parallel Aware: false
                Relation Name: "spree_corporate_accounts"
                Alias: "sca"
                Startup Cost: 0.00
                Total Cost: 1.04
                Plan Rows: 4
                Plan Width: 68
          - Node Type: "Seq Scan"
            Parent Relationship: "Inner"
            Parallel Aware: false
            Relation Name: "spree_account_prices"
            Alias: "sap"
            Startup Cost: 0.00
            Total Cost: 1.90
            Plan Rows: 4
            Plan Width: 8
            Filter: "(((status)::text = 'default'::text) AND ((accountable_type)::text = 'Spree::CorporateAccount'::text))"
      - Node Type: "Seq Scan"
        Parent Relationship: "Inner"
        Parallel Aware: false
        Relation Name: "spree_account_prices"
        Alias: "sap_1"
        Startup Cost: 0.00
        Total Cost: 1.90
        Plan Rows: 4
        Plan Width: 8
        Filter: "(((status)::text = 'temporary'::text) AND ((accountable_type)::text = 'Spree::CorporateAccount'::text))"
      - Node Type: "Seq Scan"
        Parent Relationship: "SubPlan"
        Subplan Name: "SubPlan 1"
        Parallel Aware: false
        Relation Name: "spree_variant_price_sets"
        Alias: "spree_variant_price_sets"
        Startup Cost: 0.00
        Total Cost: 1.04
        Plan Rows: 1
        Plan Width: 32
        Filter: "(id = sap.variant_price_set_id)"
      - Node Type: "Seq Scan"
        Parent Relationship: "SubPlan"
        Subplan Name: "SubPlan 2"
        Parallel Aware: false
        Relation Name: "spree_variant_price_sets"
        Alias: "spree_variant_price_sets_1"
        Startup Cost: 0.00
        Total Cost: 1.04
        Plan Rows: 1
        Plan Width: 32
        Filter: "(id = sap_1.variant_price_set_id)"
```

heres the ruby on rails with result from benchmark

```
@search = Spree::CorporateAccount.joins(memberships: [:user])
                                         .joins("LEFT JOIN ( SELECT accountable_id, accountable_type, variant_price_set_id from spree_account_prices where status = 'default' ) sap_default on sap_default.accountable_id = spree_corporate_accounts.id and sap_default.accountable_type = 'Spree::CorporateAccount' ")
                                         .joins("LEFT JOIN ( SELECT accountable_id, accountable_type, variant_price_set_id from spree_account_prices where status = 'temporary' ) sap_temporary on sap_temporary.accountable_id = spree_corporate_accounts.id and sap_temporary.accountable_type = 'Spree::CorporateAccount' ")
                                         .joins('LEFT JOIN spree_addresses ON spree_addresses.id = spree_corporate_accounts.bill_address_id')
                                         .joins('LEFT JOIN spree_states ON spree_states.id = spree_addresses.state_id')
                                         .joins('LEFT JOIN spree_countries ON spree_countries.id = spree_addresses.country_id')
                                         .where('spree_memberships.deleted_at IS NULL')
                                         .order('spree_corporate_accounts.company_name')
                                         .order('spree_memberships.admin DESC')
                                         .ransack(params[:q])
        }
```

result:

```
0.010000    0.000000    0.010000    (  0.011175)
0.030000    0.000000    0.030000    (  0.030159)
0.010000    0.000000    0.010000    (  0.012327)
0.020000    0.000000    0.020000    (  0.011852)
0.010000    0.000000    0.010000    (  0.011519)
```

pluck with select benchmark result

```
@corporate_user_list = @search.result.pluck('spree_corporate_accounts.id',
                                                    'spree_corporate_accounts.company_name',
                                                    'spree_memberships.admin',
                                                    'spree_users.email',
                                                    'spree_users.doctor AS NAME',
                                                    'coalesce(spree_corporate_accounts.account_key, spree_users.account_key) as effective_account_key',
                                                    "CASE spree_corporate_accounts.billing_type when 1 THEN 'Postbill' WHEN 2 THEN 'Creditcard' ELSE 'Individual'END",
                                                    "(SELECT name FROM spree_variant_price_sets where id = sap_default.variant_price_set_id )",
                                                    "(SELECT name FROM spree_variant_price_sets where id = sap_temporary.variant_price_set_id )",
                                                    'spree_addresses.address1',
                                                    'spree_addresses.address2',
                                                    'spree_addresses.city',
                                                    'spree_addresses.zipcode',
                                                    'spree_states.name AS state',
                                                    'spree_countries.name AS country',
                                                    'spree_addresses.phone',
                                                    "spree_users.created_at")
```

result:

```
0.040000    0.040000    0.040000    ( 53.477710)
0.020000    0.010000    0.030000    ( 32.826345)
0.030000    0.000000    0.030000    ( 34.568018)
0.030000    0.000000    0.030000    ( 23.509827)
0.030000    0.010000    0.040000    ( 45.076011)
```

so my question is which one should I use? the 1st postgres query with the inner join is slower than the postgres query with inner select. but when they are used in ruby on rails. they have different result. the inner join and pluck is much faster than the join and pluck with inner select by a significant amount. but this a raw sql wrap on ruby methods though like im confused. can you give me a link how active record initiate raw sql or maybe explain how its inner working? also when you check this on console it gives the same result on postgres, it spit out the same query. The inconsistency bothers me.

Comment: What is your goal? That may be the determining factor.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I just want to know why the benchmark is not the same. Running it on pgadmin is different from ruby but on console they will have the same output query.